# Displaying the output of JQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, variables

I can't seem to fetch some objects into a table and outputting the results. I'm wanting to capture the result of some jQuery objects.

I need to grab the Title, Description, and Link object results and toss them into a for loop and display them using a table structure. I can't seem to figure it out at all.

I am successfully pulling the data from Title, Description and Link, so now I just need to figure out how to display it using HTML.

All help would be appreciated.

Here is the output that I am aiming for:
[image]

Here is the code in my roadmap.js file:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $pnp.setup({
        baseUrl: "https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training"
    });

    $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.get().then(function(z){
        console.log(z);
        var result = z.results.map(a => ({
            Title: `${a.Title}`,
            Description: `${a.Description}`,
            Link: `${a.Link}`
            })
        );
        console.log(result);
        roadMapDisplay(result);
    })

    function roadMapDisplay(result) {
        var head = result.Title;
        var desc = result.Description; 
        var link = result.Link;

        var table = $('<table/>');
            for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                table.append('<tr/>').append('<td>' + head + '</td>');
                table.append('<tr/>').append('<td>' + desc + '</td>');
                table.append('<tr/>').append('<td>' + link + '</td>');
        }
        $('.Title').append(table);
    } 
});
```

Here is how I'm calling the html inside roadmap.txt

```html
<div class="Title"></div>

<script src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/SiteAssets/roadmap.js?v=1"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery's `.append()` should be given complete nodes, not HTML string fragments. For example, append the `<tr>` element, then append `<td>` elements to that.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't typically need `<br>` elements after blocks like `<h1>` and `<p>`. I recommend using CSS to control their vertical margins instead

Comment: Something like this? table.append('<tr>').append('<td>' + head + '</td>');?

Comment: Yes, that's on the right track though you'll want to keep a reference to the `<tr>` variable so you can add your other `<td>` elements. Also, it would be `.append('<tr/>')` or `.append('<tr></tr>')`

Comment: I went ahead and made some updates to the original code, I removed all the <h1> and <p> tags since I'll be using them inside the HTML later and I made changes to the table.append, let me know if that's the right direction.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Are you now getting something closer to the result you want? Keep in mind now you will have 3 rows with a single cell in each as opposed to what you had before

Comment: It's still not showing up sadly, I'm getting no html output at all. The above JS code is in a file called roadmap.js, I am calling it within a html file called roadmap.html

Here is the code that is being used inside the html file: <div class="Title"></div>

<script src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/SiteAssets/roadmap.js?v=1"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `roadMapDisplay` function with this one:

```
function roadMapDisplay(result) {
    $('.Title').append('<table>' + 
        result.reduce(
            (a, e) => a + 
                `<tr><td><h1>${e.Title}</h1></td>
                <td>${e.Description}</td>
                <td>${e.Link}</td></tr>`, 
            ''
        ) + '</table>'
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the update Kosh! I went ahead and replaced the roadmapDisplay function with yours but I'm still not getting the object to display.

The code above is located inside a file called roadmap.js, while I'm calling a div inside a html file using this code: <div class="Title"></div>

<script src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/SiteAssets/roadmap.js?v=1"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I am getting one step closer, I was able to get an output using the code provided below:

Does anyone know why I might be getting undefined back? I'm not getting any console.log errors.
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $pnp.setup({
        baseUrl: "https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training"
    });

    $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.get().then(function(items) {
        console.log(items);
        var result = items.map(item => {
            return {
                Title: item.Title,
                Description: item.Description,
                Link: item.Link
            }
        });
        var $table = roadMapDisplay(result);
        console.log($table);
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = $table.innerHTML;
    });

    function roadMapDisplay(items) {

        var table = $('<table/>');

        items.forEach(item => {
            table.append('<tr/>');
            table.append(`<td>${item.Title}</td>`);
            table.append(`<td>${item.Description}</td>`);
            table.append(`<td>${item.Link}</td>`);
        });

        return table;
        
    } 
});
```

```html
<div id="title"></div>

<script src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/SiteAssets/roadmap.js?v=1"></script>
```